# Two byte report count for hid report descriptor

Tags: hid, descriptor

I'm trying to create an HID report descriptor for USB 3.0 with a *report count* of 1024 bytes.

The documentation at usb.org for HID does not seem to mention a two byte report count. Nonetheless, I have seen some people use 0x96 (instead of 0x95) to enter a two byte count, such as:

0x96, 0x00, 0x02,              //   REPORT_COUNT (512)

which was taken from here:
*[Custom HID device HID report descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606991/custom-hid-device-hid-report-descriptor)*

Likewise, from this same example, 0x26 is used for a two byte logical maximum.

Where did this 0x96 and 0x26 field come from? I don't see any documentation for it.

Answer (score 2):

REPORT_COUNT is defined in the [Device Class Definition for HID 1.11](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf) document in section **6.2.2.7 Global Items** on page 36 as:

```
Report Count 1001 01 nn Unsigned integer specifying the number of data
                        fields for the item; determines how many fields are included in the
                        report for this particular item (and consequently how many bits are
                        added to the report).
```

The *nn* in the above code is the item length indicator (bSize) and is defined earlier in section **6.2.2.2 Short Items** as:

```
bSize Numeric expression specifying size of data: 
      0 = 0 bytes 
      1 = 1 byte 
      2 = 2 bytes 
      3 = 4 bytes
```

Rather confusingly, the valid values of bSize are listed in decimal. So, in binary, the bits for *nn* would be:

```
00 = 0 bytes (i.e. there is no data associated with this item)
01 = 1 byte
10 = 2 bytes
11 = 4 bytes
```

Putting it all together for REPORT_COUNT, which is an unsigned integer, the following alternatives could be specified:

```
1001 01 00 = 0x94 = REPORT_COUNT with no length (can only have value 0?)
1001 01 01 = 0x95 = 1-byte REPORT_COUNT (can have a value from 0 to 255)
1001 01 10 = 0x96 = 2-byte REPORT_COUNT (can have a value from 0 to 65535)
1001 01 11 = 0x97 = 4-byte REPORT_COUNT (can have a value from 0 to 4294967295)
```

Similarly, for LOGICAL_MAXIMUM, which is a signed integer (usually, there is an exception):

```
0010 01 00 = 0x24 = LOGICAL_MAXIMUM with no length (can only have value 0?)
0010 01 01 = 0x25 = 1-byte LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (can have a values from -128 to 127)
0010 01 10 = 0x26 = 2-byte LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (can have a value from -32768 to 32767)
0010 01 11 = 0x27 = 4-byte LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (can have a value from -2147483648 to 2147483647)
```

The specification is unclear on what value a zero-length item defaults to in general. It only mentions, at the end of section **6.2.2.4 Main Items**, that MAIN item types and, within that type, INPUT item tags, have a default value of 0:

```
Remarks - The default data value for all Main items is zero (0).
        - An Input item could have a data size of zero (0) bytes. In this case the value of
          each data bit for the item can be assumed to be zero. This is functionally
          identical to using a item tag that specifies a 4-byte data item followed by four
          zero bytes.
```

It would be reasonable to assume 0 as the default for other item types too, but for REPORT_COUNT (a GLOBAL item) a value of 0 is not really a sensible default (IMHO). The specification doesn't really say.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Unspecified zero-sized items are not accepted by Windows HID parser (while they work on Mac OS, iOS and Linux).