# How to parse hid report descriptor?

Tags: usb, driver, hid

All the tutorials I've read about usb hid report descriptors use numbers to represent data. Where do these numbers come from?

Example:

```
0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Mouse)
0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
0xa1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
0x05, 0x09,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
0x19, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
0x29, 0x03,                    //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3)
0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x95, 0x03,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75, 0x05,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (5)
0x81, 0x03,                    //     INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x05, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
0x15, 0x81,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
0x25, 0x7f,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
0x75, 0x08,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x81, 0x06,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
```

For example, where does the 0x05 and 0x01 in the first line come from? How does that transalate to // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)? What are valid values? How are these ordered? How is nesting defined?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to a similar question at [Custom HID device HID report descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606991/custom-hid-device-hid-report-descriptor) (extract follows):

> To understand HID Report Descriptors you need to read some of the documents on the [HID Information page](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/). In particular, you should try to understand:

1. The "Device Class Definition for HID 1.11" document - which describes the Human Interface Device report format
2. The "HID Usage Tables 1.3" document - which describes the values of many Usage Pages and Usages within those pages that can appear in a Report Descriptor